# Как отцентрировать выпадающее меню относительно его родителя?

Tags: html, css

Как отцентрировать выпадающее меню относительно его родителя?

**Код:**

```css
.cats {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cat {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.cat-parent {
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cat:hover .cat-hidden {
  display: block;
}

.cat-hidden {
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cat-child {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cats">
  <div class="cat">
    <a href="#" class="cat-parent">s</a>
    <div class="cat-hidden">
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">Link 1Link 1Link 1Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">Link 4</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">Link 5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Ссылка на полный код](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JQQmgL)

**Как сейчас:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как нужно:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возьмите их общий контейнер, и отцентрируй их в общем контейнере. Почитайте про БЭМ)

Answer (score 1):

Например с `absolute`:

```css
.cats {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.cat-parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 15px;
}
.cat:hover .cat-hidden {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.cat-hidden {
  display: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
.cat-child {
  color: #fff;
  padding:  15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cats">
  <div class="cat">
    <a href="#" class="cat-parent">s1</a>
    <div class="cat-hidden">
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">1Link 1Link 1Link 1Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">1Link 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">1Link 3</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">1Link 4</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">1Link 5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cat">
    <a href="#" class="cat-parent">s2</a>
    <div class="cat-hidden">
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">2Link 1Link 1Link 1Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">2Link 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">2Link 3</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">2Link 4</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">2Link 5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cat">
    <a href="#" class="cat-parent">s3</a>
    <div class="cat-hidden">
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">3Link 1Link 1Link 1Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">3Link 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">3Link 3</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">3Link 4</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">3Link 5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cat">
    <a href="#" class="cat-parent">s4</a>
    <div class="cat-hidden">
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">4Link 1Link 1Link 1Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">4Link 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">4Link 3</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">4Link 4</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">4Link 5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста почему position: relative задаётся главному родителю, а не .cat? Для чего нужен left:  50% у .cat-hidden? За что отвечает transform:translateX(-50%);? Спасибо!

Comment: @Кот, https://webref.ru/ ознакомьтесь с основами верстки, чтобы понять такие простые вещи!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно так.

```css
.cats {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cat-parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 15px;
}
.cat:hover .cat-hidden {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.cat-hidden {
  display: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.cat-child {
  color: #fff;
  padding:  15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cats">
  <div class="cat">
    <a href="#" class="cat-parent">s</a>
    <div class="cat-hidden">
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">Link 1Link 1Link 1Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">Link 4</a>
      <a href="#" class="cat-child">Link 5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMNjMR не совсем подходит решение